# How do I issue a compiler error for invalid argument to a consteval function?

Tags: c++, constexpr, consteval

I wanted to implement utility literals for evaluating roots of numbers. I implemented suffix literals that return root functions. Here's my code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdexcept>

class RootFunc {
    double exp;
public:
    constexpr RootFunc(auto root): exp(1.0/root) {}

    constexpr auto operator()(auto number) {
        return std::pow(number, exp);
    }
};

#define ERROR_STRING(alt) \
    "Please use the `" alt "` suffix literal"

consteval RootFunc operator"" th_root(unsigned long long int n) {
    int last_digit = n % 10;

    // Ensure users use the right suffix literal
    if (n < 11 || n > 13) {
        if (last_digit == 1) {
            throw std::invalid_argument(ERROR_STRING("st_root"));
        } else if (last_digit == 2) {
            throw std::invalid_argument(ERROR_STRING("nd_root"));
        } else if (last_digit == 3) {
            throw std::invalid_argument(ERROR_STRING("rd_root"));
        }
    }

    return RootFunc(n);
}


consteval RootFunc operator"" st_root(unsigned long long int n) {
    int last_digit = n % 10;

    // Ensure users use the right suffix literal
    if ((n >= 11 && n <= 13) || last_digit >= 4) {
        throw std::invalid_argument(ERROR_STRING("th_root"));
    } else if (last_digit == 2) {
        throw std::invalid_argument(ERROR_STRING("nd_root"));
    } else if (last_digit == 3) {
        throw std::invalid_argument(ERROR_STRING("rd_root"));
    }
    return RootFunc(n);
}

consteval RootFunc operator"" nd_root(unsigned long long int n) {
    int last_digit = n % 10;

    // Ensure users use the right suffix literal
    if ((n >= 11 && n <= 13) || last_digit >= 4) {
        throw std::invalid_argument(ERROR_STRING("th_root"));
    } else if (last_digit == 1) {
        throw std::invalid_argument(ERROR_STRING("st_root"));
    } else if (last_digit == 3) {
        throw std::invalid_argument(ERROR_STRING("rd_root"));
    }
    return RootFunc(n);
}

consteval RootFunc operator"" rd_root(unsigned long long int n) {
    int last_digit = n % 10;

    // Ensure users use the right suffix literal
    if ((n >= 11 && n <= 13) || last_digit >= 4) {
        throw std::invalid_argument(ERROR_STRING("th_root"));
    } else if (last_digit == 2) {
        throw std::invalid_argument(ERROR_STRING("nd_root"));
    } else if (last_digit == 1) {
        throw std::invalid_argument(ERROR_STRING("st_root"));
    }
    return RootFunc(n);
}

#undef ERROR_STRING


#include <iostream>

#define SHOW(expr) \
    (std::cout << #expr << " = " << (expr) << std::endl)

int main() {
    SHOW(4th_root(81));
    SHOW(21st_root(200));
    SHOW(2nd_root(4));
    SHOW(3rd_root(27));
    SHOW(11th_root(1001));

    // This should fail:
    // SHOW(1th_root(3));
    // SHOW(11st_root(91));
    // SHOW(23nd_root(1009));
}

#undef SHOW
```

I want to issue a compiler error when a user calls the wrong suffix literal. In my implementation, I raised an exception. While this does cause the compilation to fail, it doesn't communicate what really happened. The compilation fails because the `throw` clause is not a constant expression. I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. I tried using `static_assert` but I get an error that `n` is not a constant expression, which I don't understand why, given that the function is `consteval`.

Please can someone tell me if there's a better way to issue a compiler error for an illegal argument in a `consteval` function?

Comment: Replace the throw expression with a call to a non-`constexpr` function whose name contains diagnostic information?

Comment: The reason `static_assert` can't use `consteval` parameters is that it reuses the same machinery used for template arguments—constant expressions. Template instantiations are a problem during constant evaluation, so `static_assert` suffers the same requirements even though it doesn't need to. To my limited knowledge, the standard could be tweaked to allow `consteval` parameters in a `static_assert` by simply saying they're allowed in that context, but you'd still run into questions like "Why does `static_assert(n != 0);` work, but `static_assert(foo<n>);` doesn't?"

Comment: @康桓瑋 That seems like a viable option. Thank you.

Comment: @chris You're right. I think the problem is that the C++ standard forgot the fact that if a function execution is happening in a constant expression context, then all its arguments or local variables even if not declared as `constexpr` should be implicitly `constexpr`.